# How can I put images in a LaTeX document

Tags: graphics

Suppose I have a LaTeX document, and I wanted to add a jpg file to the document. How would I do that?

For example, if I had a jpg file called `graph.jpg`, how would I add it to the below LaTeX document, under the formula for W<sub>net</sub>?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\Huge

Formulae in \LaTeX\\

\vspace{1cm}

\LARGE
$W_{net}=\int\vec{F}\cdot\,d\vec{s}$\\


\end{document}
```

Comment: use `graphicx` package and `\includegraphics{graph}`  (and remove those `\\ ` which are generating warnings for good reason)

Comment: this will be in every latex tutorial eg https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-07